# How to disable a index of a alertview in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uialertview

I need to disable a alerview index according to a flag value.

**my alerview is :**

```
UIAlertView * alert =[[UIAlertView alloc ] initWithTitle:@"Reminder" message:@"Send a reminder through" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles: nil];
[alert addButtonWithTitle:@"Email"];
[alert addButtonWithTitle:@"SMS"];
[alert addButtonWithTitle:@"TS"];
[alert addButtonWithTitle:@"Cancel"];
[alert show];
```

i am having a flag named isCheck=0 or 1

if isCheck=1 I have to disable the button index named SMS. Can anyone help

Comment: set button.tag and get the view from tag and disable it.

Comment: how to create a tag for each button index. i have created tag for a alertview ?

Comment: When your isCheck value gets changed? @Arun

Comment: its a result from webservice @ ronak

Comment: So, what you can do is [alert addButtonWithTitle:@"SMS"] only if isCheck=1 @Arun

Comment: ok i will try @ronak

Comment: it worked @ Ronak but handiling in - (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex the button index geting changed while hiding the  [alert addButtonWithTitle:@"SMS"]

Comment: What you want to handle in didDismissWithButtonIndex method? @Arun

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can try is like below code:

SMS button will only be added if isCheck is 1.

```
UIAlertView * alert =[[UIAlertView alloc ] initWithTitle:@"Reminder" message:@"Send a reminder through" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [alert addButtonWithTitle:@"Email"];

    if (isCheck==1) {
        [alert addButtonWithTitle:@"SMS"];
    }
    [alert addButtonWithTitle:@"TS"];
    [alert addButtonWithTitle:@"Cancel"];

    [alert show];
```

Add below delegate methods to your code to handle anything on particular button click of `UIAlertView`:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alert didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {

NSString *title = [alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];

    if([title isEqualToString:@"Email"])
    {
        NSLog(@"Email");
    }
    if([title isEqualToString:@"SMS"])
    {
        NSLog(@"SMS");
    }
    if([title isEqualToString:@"TS"])
    {
        NSLog(@"TS");
    }
    if([title isEqualToString:@"Cancel"])
    {
        NSLog(@"Cancel");
    }

}
```

OR

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    NSString *title = [alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];

        if([title isEqualToString:@"Email"])
        {
            //Email button Clicked: Do whatever you want
            NSLog(@"Email");
        }
        if([title isEqualToString:@"SMS"])
        {
            //SMS button Clicked: Do whatever you want
            NSLog(@"SMS");

            //Call your Web Service
            if(isCheck==1){
              //Do something
            }
            else{
             //Do Nothing
            }

        }
        if([title isEqualToString:@"TS"])
        {
            //TS button Clicked: Do whatever you want
            NSLog(@"TS");
        }
        if([title isEqualToString:@"Cancel"])
        {
            //Cancel button Clicked: Do whatever you want
            NSLog(@"Cancel");
        }
    }
```

Comment: how to handle in - (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex

Comment: its is awsom man @ronak can i make the SMS button visible but user sholuld not perform any action while pressing.

Comment: if you do not want anything on SMS button click then don't handle anything in  if([title isEqualToString:@"SMS"])
    {
        NSLog(@"SMS");
    }

Comment: i have a web service call in all button index.

Comment: in the web service result i get a (isCheck=0 or 1) flag if 0 the button index should be shown and user should not perform any task by pressing. if it is 0 user can perform the task .